# DNS configuration for accessing consul remotely

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, consul

I have installed `consul` on AWS EC2, with 3 servers and 1 client.

server IPs = 11.XX.XX.1,11.XX.XX.2,11.XX.XX.3.
client IP  = 11.XX.XX.4

`consul` config: /etc/consul.d/server/config.json

```
{
    "bootstrap": false,
    "server": true,
    "datacenter": "abc",
    "advertise_addr": "11.XX.XX.1",
    "data_dir": "/var/consul",
    "log_level": "INFO",
    "enable_syslog": true,
    "addresses": {
    "http": "0.0.0.0"
    },
    "start_join": ["11.XX.XX.2", "11.XX.XX.3"]
}
```

`netstat` output on server:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8400          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29720/consul    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1006/sshd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8600          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29720/consul    
tcp6       0      0 :::8301                 :::*                    LISTEN      29720/consul    
tcp6       0      0 :::8302                 :::*                    LISTEN      29720/consul    
tcp6       0      0 :::8500                 :::*                    LISTEN      29720/consul    
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1006/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::8300                 :::*                    LISTEN      29720/consul
```

`curl` is working fine from remote machine but `dig` is only working on the local machine.

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.6-Ubuntu <<>> @127.0.0.1 -p 8600 web.service.consul
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 40873
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;web.service.consul.        IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
web.service.consul. 0   IN  A   11.XX.XX.4

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#8600(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Dec 30 08:21:41 UTC 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 52
```

but `dig` is not working from remote machine:

```
dig @11.XX.XX.1 -p 8600 web.service.consul

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.6-Ubuntu <<>> @11.XX.XX.1 -p 8600 web.service.consul
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
-----------------------------
```

How to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

By default consul only listens for DNS connections on the instance loopback device. Best practices asks you to install the client on any remote machine looking to consume consul DNS. This is not always practical.

I have seen people expose DNS (consul port 8600) on all interfaces via the Consul configuration JSON like so:

```
{
   "server": true,
   "addresses": {
     "dns": "0.0.0.0"
   }
}
```

You can also expose all ports listening on loopback with the client_addr field in JSON or pass it via the command line with:

```
consul agent -client 0.0.0.0
```

There are more controls and knobs available to tweak (see docs):

https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html

Comment: when you say expose DNS on all interface, what does it mean?

Comment: I guess problem is with resolv.conf as AWS overwrite it .

Comment: Anything on loopback interface is only available to the machine it is running on. By default Consul DNS only listens on loopback device. That is why you can not access DNS with dig from the other instance. Expose DNS on all interfaces tells the Consul application to listen for inbound DNS requests on all the interfaces (not just the restricted loopback device) This allows other instances to communicate with this instance using normal IPs. Of course this is ruling out any firewall or connectivity issues between the two instances.